# How to delete parent row when delete child row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Lets assume I have 3 tables.

1. Students
2. College
3. CollegeStudents

`Students` table consist of all students (all college students) data. `College` table consist of all college data. And `CollegeStudents` table consist of a mapping of Students and College. I'm not using soft delete. When I delete college, I can easily remove `CollegeStudents` data by using relationship since `CollegeStudents` is a child of `College`.(onDelete('cascade')). But my problem is, I want to remove students from `Students` table as well when deleting the College row. How come it is possible. Is there any way in **mysql** to manage this kind of criteria? I'm using **Laravel** eloquent.

Advance thanks for your help.

Comment: It is simple, you just need to use college id as foreign id in student table. So when you will delete any college you use same id for student table.

Comment: you can not .. because you are using belongsToMany both ways .. that only means .. even if you delete the college , those students under that college may belong to another college .. so you can not delete it .. if you really want something like that you must fix the relation between college and students .. you might use College hasMany students .. and Students belongsTo College ..

Answer (score 2):

use college id in the student table as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of @V-Wanderer you can specify in your migrations what to do with foreign key relations.

**Example**

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
      ->references('id')->on('users')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Will delete the relation as expected

> reference_option:
>       RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add foreign key, you can add method at College model:

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted(function($college)
    {
        foreach($college->students as $student) {
            $student->delete();
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, you need to defined also `students` method at same model (like bellow).

```
public function students()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

Method `students` depends on how you are targeting students with relation into college...

Source: [LINK](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-delete-model-with-all-relations)